# $E(X\mid X+Y)$, where $X$ and $Y$ are independent $U(0,1)$.

Tags: probability, functions, expectation, convolution

Given that $X,Y\sim U(0,1)$ calculate:

(1) $E(X\mid X+Y)$

I am stuck at this point:

$$E(X\mid X+Y)=\int_0^1 xf_{X\mid X+Y}(x\mid x+Y) \, dx=\int_0^1 xf_{X, Y}(x, Y) \, dx$$

Comment: Another option: By symmetry, E(X|X+Y)=E(Y|X+Y), and, by definition, E(X+Y|X+Y)=X+Y hence E(X|X+Y)=... Does not use the common distribution of X and Y.

Comment: Thank you! But the next question is to calculate $E(X^2|X+Y)$ and then I will not be able to use this fact.

Comment: Sounds like *another* question to me.

Comment: Use $X|S\sim U(0\vee(S-1),1\wedge S)$ and consider $S<1$ and $S>1$ separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know $(X,X+Y)\sim U(D)$ (i.e., a uniform distribution over $D$), where $D$ is the shaded area as below:

[image: joint distribution]

So $$
X\mid X+Y\sim 
\begin{cases}
U[0,X+Y] & \text{if } 0\le X+Y\le 1\\
U[X+Y-1,1] & \text{if } 1\le X+Y \le 2
\end{cases}
$$

In either case, $E[X\mid X+Y]=\frac{1}{2}(X+Y)$.

Answer (score 2):

The answer in the comment by "Did" is probably the best way to do this, but I think we should also look at how to deal correctly with your integral.

pair $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed in the square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.  If $0\le s\le 2$, the the set of points where $X+Y = s$ is a line segment passing diagonally through the square.  Given the event $X+Y=s$, the random variable $X$ is uniformly distributed on that segment.  If $0\le s\le 1$ then $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,s]$; if $1\le s\le 2$ then $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[s-1,1]$. (Draw the picture and you'll see that.)  Either way, $X$ is uniformly distributed on $\big[\max\{s-1,0\}, \min\{1,s\}\big]$.  Hence
$$
f_{X\,\mid\,X+Y=s} (x) = \begin{cases}
\left.\begin{cases} 1/s & \text{if } 0<x<s \\ 0 & \text{if }x<0 \text{ or }x>s \end{cases} \right\} & \text{if } 0\le s\le 1, \\[10pt]
\left.\begin{cases} 1/(2 - s) & \text{if } s-1<x<1, \\ 0 & \text{if } x<s-1, \text{ or } s>2 \end{cases} \right\} & \text{if } 1\le s\le 2.
\end{cases}
$$
Consequently
$$
f_{X\,\mid\,X+Y} (x) = \begin{cases}
\left.\begin{cases} 1/(X+Y) & \text{if } 0<x<X+Y \\ 0 & \text{if }x<0 \text{ or }x>X+Y \end{cases} \right\} & \text{if } 0\le X+Y\le 1, \\[10pt]
\left.\begin{cases} 1/(2 - X - Y) & \text{if } X+Y-1<x<1, \\ 0 & \text{if } x<X+Y-1, \text{ or } X+Y>2 \end{cases} \right\} & \text{if } 1\le X+Y\le 2.
\end{cases}
$$
So you need
$$
\int_0^2 x f_{X\,\mid \, X+Y}(x)\,dx = \begin{cases} \displaystyle \int_0^{X+Y} \frac x {X+Y}  \, dx & \text{if }0\le X+Y\le 1, \\[8pt] \displaystyle \int_{X+Y-1}^1 \frac x {2-X-Y} \, dx & \text{if }1\le X+Y\le 2. \end{cases}
$$
Either way, the value of the integral is $\dfrac{X+Y}2$. To get that from the second integral, I had to know that
$$
\frac 1 2 \cdot\frac{1 - (X+Y-1)^2}{2-X-Y} = \frac 1 2 \cdot \frac{(2-X-Y)(X+Y)}{2-X-Y},
$$
and it might have taken me a while to figure that out if I had not had $\text{“}$Did$\text{''}$'s solution to guide me.

So:

- You need to be fairly careful in setting up the integrals; and
- You should be able to use the above to find $\operatorname{E}(X^2\mid X+Y)$.